# Uploading file to Dropbox with Cordova

Tags: cordova, dropbox, dropbox-api, phonegap, dropbox-sdk

I have a file on device locally. I want to upload this file to Dropbox. Almost all is done, but I cannot figure out what should be the value of the `contents` property of the object? I am using `cordova file plugin` to get the file url and Dropbox SDK for uploading. Here's the code. Lets say i want to upload an MP3 or a ZIP file...

```
let dbx = new Dropbox({ clientId: CLIENT_ID })
dbx.filesUpload({
            path: "/" + fileName,
            contents: XXXXXXXX, // what should be the value of this?
            mode: "overwrite",
            mute: true,
            autorename: false,
            strict_conflict: false
        })
            .then(response => { 
                 // do something with success
        })
            .catch(error => {
                // do something with error
        })
```

Comment: You should pass the actual file data that you want to upload to the `contents` parameter. There's [an example here for node](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/b2353edeb221ec17b8e70a1d8fd4799e2f1f031d/examples/javascript/node/upload.js#L23), for instance.

Comment: @Greg thanks for the link Greg. However, I am not sure whether to read the file as as Array Buffer or as a dataURI would be better? Also, won't these methods be memory intensive and make the app/device slow, especially when uploading big files like 150mb or so? And yet another thing is whether the file will be "openable" as it was originally? Example: If I read a .zip file using one of the methods and then download the file later, will it still open as ZIP?

Comment: I see you opened a new question for these, so I'll try to offer some help there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56575928/how-to-upload-a-file-to-dropbox-using-js-sdk/56583287#56583287